# Is there a way for me to view my work or my whole iMac screen in grayscale?

Tags: macos, display, imac, sound-volume, quarkxpress

I am working on a job that will be published in print and online in grayscale. Most of the creative work is being created in QuarkXPress.

**My problem is that I really need to see how this is going to look in grayscale.**

Up until now I have been exporting the work to PDF in grayscale to see how things look, but as you can imagine this is a slow process.

**Is there a setting anywhere in QuarkXPress 9.5.4.0 I can use to view my files in grayscale, or a setting within Mac OS X 10.11.6 that I can use to make my iMac temporarily display in grayscale?**

Answer (score 11, accepted):

**Yes you can!**

Follow these steps:

1. Go to Apple > System Preferences > Accessibility
2. In the left hand pane make sure *Display* is selected
3. On the right hand side you’ll see a number of checkboxes and sliders
4. Tick the *Use grayscale* checkbox

Your iMac’s display should immediately switch to grayscale mode.

**TIP:** Since you only need grayscale while you’re working on this job, you can tick the *Show Accessibility status in menu bar* checkbox at bottom left of the Accessibility preferences. This way you can access this setting as you need directly from the menu bar.